# Determine probability from input data (Hypergeometric distribution?)

Tags: probability

I appologize for not being very specific in the title as I don't really understand if this is the correct way to solve the following problem.

I've stumbled upon this:

While playing a Lottery 6/49 game, you have the following three categories:
1) Category 1 -> 6 numbers
2) Category 2 -> 5 numbers
3) Category 3 -> 4 numbers

Given a total number of marbles, number of extracted marbles and category (one of the above), determine the probability of winning the game.

Example:
For 40 marbles, 5 extracted marbles and category II : 0.0002659542

From what I've found so far, one way to solve it would be using the hypergeometric distribution formula, but I can't seem to find a way to get a result near close using this example. Could someone tell me if this is right at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You´re right that the question can be solved by using the hypergeometric distribution. You have $40$ marbles. You draw $5$ marbles. From the result I´ve conclude that $4$ marbles are right and one marble is wrong. You have $K=5, N-K=40-5, k=4$ and $n-k=5-4$. We use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) formula and plug in the numbers:

$$P(X = k) 
=\frac{\binom{K}{k}\cdot  \binom{N - K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}= \frac{\binom{5}{4} \cdot \binom{35}{1}}{\binom{40}{5}}=\frac{5\cdot 35 }{\frac{40\cdot 39\cdot 38\cdot 37\cdot 36}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5}}=0.0002659542$$

Comment: Wow, the wiki explanations got me confused in the way the numbers should be inputed. Clear now, thank you!!

Comment: @cipriRusu You´re welcome. If you don´t have questions anymore you can mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: If you don't mind i'd like to clarify something. Where did you come up with the 4 marbles right/1marble wrong? Or to put it in another way, did you use any of the three categories with the formula to find the answer? I mean if I'm supposed to use this formula in another context (given a number of total marbles/extracted marbles/category) can it be done just like this?

Comment: @cipriRusu It always depends how something is defined. Here a category $j$ is defined as follows: If you choose $i$  numbers of a sequence with length $m$ then the category is $j=m-i+1$. If you choose 5 out of 6 numbers then the category $j$ is $6-5+1=2$. And if you choose 4 out of 5 numbers the category $j$ is $5-4+1=2$ as well.